# Travis CI bootstrap failed

Tags: r, travis-ci

I use Travis CI to check my [R package](https://github.com/surmann/ODEnetwork). Unfortunately the Travis CI build fails with the message `The command "./travis-tool.sh bootstrap" failed and exited with 1 during .`.

The commit [93d2451](https://github.com/surmann/ODEnetwork/commit/93d24518c7df73dd654495d66696185d99faeea6) passes Travis CI and after that commit I made only an update of the readme. Does anyone has a glue why Travis CI throws this error?

Comment: Glue I have none of but I think you may have to add `sudo: required` to the .yml per: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/

Comment: I updated to native R support. However, I had to add `sudo: required`. This is interesting, because a colleague uses the same `.travis.yml` as I did and had a successful build: https://travis-ci.org/jakobbossek/ecr